# Fedora 20 rescue mode from USB stick

Tags: fedora, rescue

I have a Fedora 20 KDE on a 512 mini SSD disk. Yesterday I unfortunately downloaded many rar-files into my `/root` partition and ran this command afterwards: `unrar x *.rar`. So what happened? My PC got stuck and I could not do anything more so I pushed the power off button as hardly as I can. After I started it again my Fedora stuck at this part
`Failed to write pack file`. So my thoughts are that my root partition is full.

My question know how to get this files deleted?

**What I tried:**
I downloaded a Fedora 20 Live Image and copied into a USB stick. After that I tried to boot from the USB stick to get into the rescue mode. But I don't have a submenu under `Troubleshooting` which contains something like `rescue mode`. No problem I thought because I saw that someone said you have to run `Linux rescue` from the grub. I did that, but I got another error message that it could not find a kernel named Linux. Fine so I googled more and more. I saw a post that the Fedora Live CD does not have a rescue mode. I have to start the Live CD and mount my existing fedora OS. But this did not help either.

So does anybody know what to do now?

Comment: Why didn't mounting the drive help? If you mounted the drive as root you will be able to erase the files you unrared.

Comment: You can use any live rescue cd, it doesn't have to be Fedora.
`/root` isn't usually a partition (though it could be), likely a directory on `/`. You need to know which filesystem to mount, then mount it and clean it. SysRescueCD is fairly stable and robust.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to go into a special rescue mode. Boot the Live image, and instead of running the installer, fire up a terminal and use that to repair your existing system.

Answer (score 0):

download boot.iso

http://mirrors.eu.kernel.org/fedora/releases/20/Fedora/x86_64/os/images/boot.iso or 
http://mirrors.eu.kernel.org/fedora/releases/20/Fedora/i386/os/images/boot.iso

we can put boot.iso on a usb stick , in same way that we put live images, describe in USB Booting :
usb must be on vfat or else format usb with:

```
# mkfs.vfat /dev/sdb1.

# /usr/bin/livecd-iso-to-disk boot.iso /dev/sdb1
```

also you may test is USB  boot with :

```
qemu-system-i386 -hda /dev/sdb -boot a
```

my references:

http://www.serjux.com/freedos_boot/Create-a-bootable-rescue.txt

http://www.serjux.com/freedos_boot/Createabootableusbandcheckifboots.txt at the end of the page